# Basic exercise on "expect" - beginner

Tags: debugging, unix, expect

I am a beginner learning the tool "expect", I am trying out several exercises at this stage.

Below is a simple exercise illustrating the use of two consecutive "spawn" commands -- to change the password of unix system and then restore the old. Basically, automating what one does manually:

```
$passwd
Changing password for <username>.
(current) UNIX password: 
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
```

The problem is that "expect" mysteriously stops at the entry of the second spawn waiting for the prompt.. keeping me in an endless mystery.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

#PREAMBLE
set timeout -1
set force_conservative 1
set send_slow {1 .1}
if {$force_conservative} {
    set send_slow {1 .1}
    proc send {ignore arg} {
        sleep .1
        exp_send -s -- $arg
    }
}

#ACTUAL CODE
spawn passwd

expect "(current)"
send -- "PW-OLD\r"

expect "Enter"
send -- "PW-NEW\r"

expect "Retype"
send -- "PW-NEW\r"

sleep 1

spawn passwd

expect "(current)"
send -- "PW-NEW"

expect "Enter"
send -- "PW-OLD\r"

expect "Retype"
send -- "PW-OLD\r"
interact
```

I would also love to hear any bad practices that you notice, and any good practices that you may want to tell.

Below is the output of `expect -d` (replacing `expect -f` in the first shebang line), after the suggestion of user @pynexj. This looks like the actual coder's debug utility, that I was not aware of.

```
$./exercise1.sh
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = /usr/bin/expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = ./exercise1.sh  
set argc 0
set argv0 "./exercise1.sh"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file ./exercise1.sh
spawn passwd
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {7848}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "(current)"? no
Changing password for <username>.
(current) UNIX password: 
expect: does "Changing password for <username>.\r\n(current) UNIX password: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "(current)"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "(current)"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Changing password for <username>.\r\n(current)"
send: sending "PW-OLD\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does " UNIX password: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "Enter"? no


expect: does " UNIX password: \r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "Enter"? no
Enter new UNIX password: 
expect: does " UNIX password: \r\nEnter new UNIX password: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "Enter"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Enter"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " UNIX password: \r\nEnter"
send: sending "PW-NEW\r" to { exp4 }

expect: does " new UNIX password: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "Retype"? no


expect: does " new UNIX password: \r\n" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "Retype"? no
Retype new UNIX password: 
expect: does " new UNIX password: \r\nRetype new UNIX password: " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "Retype"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "Retype"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp4"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " new UNIX password: \r\nRetype"
send: sending "PW-NEW\r" to { exp4 }
spawn passwd
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {7861}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "(current)"? no
Changing password for <username>.
(current) UNIX password: 
expect: does "Changing password for <username>.\r\n(current) UNIX password: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "(current)"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "(current)"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp7"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "Changing password for <username>.\r\n(current)"
send: sending "PW-NEW" to { exp7 }

expect: does " UNIX password: " (spawn_id exp7) match glob pattern "Enter"? no
^Csighandler: handling signal(2)
async event handler: Tcl_Eval(exit 130)
```

Comment: u need to wait for the first `spawn` to exit or there will be two `passwd` processes running for one single user.

Comment: @pynexj I did wait for a full second, right? passwd exits faster than that, after retyping the password.. Anyhow, I tried with even 10seconds, it didn't work. I also used "exit" command explicitly before the second spawn, still it didn't work.. I also tried "wait", "close".

Comment: ok if u r sure though it's exactly the *bad practices* u r asking for.

Comment: `expect -d` your script and see more details.

Comment: @pynexj After `expect -d`, realized that when expect is waiting for the string "Enter", it got a string different from that!! Any suggestions?? I obviously can't guess which part of the output string comes to its mind!

Comment: u have `expect "Enter"` in ur code. u need to know in advance what the command would output.

Comment: another *good practice* is *dont send too early*. make sure to see the full prompt (e.g. `Enter` vs. `Enter the passwd: `) before `send`ing.

Comment: @pynexj I got the error. Waiting for a string that is not at the end of the output is the problem. Thanks a lot, @pynexj!! To close, one last Q: How to ensure the earlier spawn has ended?? `wait` or `wait -nowait` or `close` or `expect eof`??

Comment: Also, @pynexj: I can accept the answer, if you can write it down :)) (You could also upvote my question?)

Comment: on the way home. later.

Comment: 1) `expect eof` is usually used to wait for the spawned process to exit. 2) `wait` is used to get the exit status and reclaim process resources (like PID). use `-nowait` if u dont care about the exit status. 3) `close` is a way to *close* (actually `kill -HUP`) the spawned process which is just like u close a terminal window while the shell's still running. 4) `interact` also waits for the process to exit though its a bit weird to me to use it for this purpose. one better thing with `interact` is u don't worry about the timeout which u need to be careful of with `expect eof`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regex pattern that applies to all the password prompts:

```
expect -re "password: $"
```

Change both `sleep 1` and `interact` to `expect eof`

```tcl
# create new password
spawn passwd
expect -re "password: $"; send -- "PW-OLD\r"
expect -re "password: $"; send -- "PW-NEW\r"
expect -re "password: $"; send -- "PW-NEW\r"
expect eof

# restore old password
spawn passwd
expect -re "password: $"; send -- "PW-NEW\r"
expect -re "password: $"; send -- "PW-OLD\r"
expect -re "password: $"; send -- "PW-OLD\r"
expect eof
```

---

With glob patterns, if you don't specify any wildcards, you're basically doing string equality checking. You could do:

```
expect "*(current) UNIX password: "
expect "*Enter new UNIX password: "
expect "*Retype new UNIX password: "
```

Note the trailing spaces, which are present in the passwd prompts.

Comment: `expect *foo` is the same as `expec foo`. just like with RE `expect -re .*foo` is the same as `expect -re foo`.